# Prevent cat from opening a binary file

Tags: linux, shell, cat

Is there a way to prevent or prompt you when trying to `cat` binary files?

Oftentimes I need to work with log files or data files, some of which are text and others not. It's easy to get mixed up, and accidentally trying to `cat` a binary file is annoying for obvious reasons.

Ideally I'd want an alias to `cat` that will prompt you if it detects a file is (with high probability) not plaintext.

Comment: its not ideal but using cat -e binary.file will convert all non printing characters and avoid your screen beeping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't think this is worth it when you could just check before `cat`ing something, but you could set up a function in your `~/.bashrc` to do this:

```
cat(){
    for i in "$@"
    do
        if  file --mime "$i" | grep "charset=binary" >/dev/null 
        then
            printf "File %s is binary, skipping\n" "$i" >&2
        else
            /bin/cat "$i"
        fi
    done
}
```

That will run `file` to check if the file's mime-type is `charset=binary` and, if so, it will skip it. If that test fails, the file is not binary and `/bin/cat` is called. You can use it just like you would the regular cat:

```
$ cat /bin/bash /etc/os-release
File "/bin/bash" is binary, skipping
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint LMDE"
NAME="Linux Mint LMDE"
ID=linuxmint
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you call `file` with `-i` it will return the mime type allowing you to determine if it is text or not.

```
file -i file.name | grep text/ && cat file.name
```

if `file.name` is binary the `&&` does not execute the `cat` and if its plain text then it does.

This now matches script and other "text" files that are not marked as "plain"

Comment: That will fail on non-binary files that are not "text.plain". For example, shell scripts, python scripts, perl scripts etc. Not to mention html files and all the myriad text files that are not shown as "text-plain".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [said here](https://superuser.com/a/890704/257269) you can **simply 
use `less`**  instead of `cat`.

It prompts if the file is not a regular one, and give some plus as, for example, the list of the files in a zip,rar archive...

By the way you can use even `cat -v` that will transform non reading characters without adding a `$` to the end of each line.

Answer (score -1):

Save this as a script for example `newcat.sh`, and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=`file $1 | grep -c "binary"`
if [ "$result" -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "executable file"
else
        cat $1
fi
```

then use it as `./newcat.sh filename`

Comment: That will still print binary files that aren't LSB executables. Compressed archives and pdfs for example.

Comment: Corrected to include all binaries.

Comment: That's worse actually :) Still fails on pdfs and tarballs but now also fails on regular executable files (try `/bin/ls` for example) Better but that still fails on many (all?) binary formats. None of the files in my `/bin` directory are reported as 'binary'. Is anything?

Comment: @terdon My `file` reports "data" when it can't figure out the format. (Tried it on some garbage from /dev/urandom.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling yes, that's why I'm using the `mimetype` in my answer. That returns `application/octet-stream; charset=binary` for data from `urandom`.